# How to use take and skip for bulk data entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, skip, take

In my database have 1 million member data. and need to load those data to grid. I have following code.

```
public List<MemberDto> GetMembers(string By = "", string searchTerm = "", string sortBy = "", string sortDiection = "")
{
    List<EFModel.ClientData.Member> members = context.Members.ToList();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(By))
    {
        if (By.ToLower() == "a")
        {
            members = members.Where(m => m.MemberNumber.IndexOf(searchTerm, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0).ToList();
        }
        else if (By.ToLower() == "n")
        {
            members = members.Where(m => m.LastName.IndexOf(searchTerm, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0).ToList();
        }
    }
    List<MemberDto> memberDtos = new List<MemberDto>();
    mapper.Map(members, memberDtos);
    return memberDtos;
}
```

before I bind the above data to the grid data source. I'm doing the pagination. by set only 25 records for each grid view. but problem is it will take some considerable time fetch data, therefor I need do that pagination part and search part inside the above method.

So , I tried this query.

```
int pageIndex = 1; 
int page size = 25;


var members = (from m in context.Members
                where (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm) || m.MemberNumber.Contains(searchTerm))
                        && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm) || m.LastName.Contains(searchTerm))
                select m).ToList().Skip(pageIndex).Take(size);
```

But this taking some considerable time to execute, what did I do wrong. How do I fix this issue. I just want to get data by `searchTerm` and `pageSize` and `pageIndex`. In above `By` can be **`a`** or **`n`**. **`a`** for MemberNumber and **`n`** for LastName

Comment: How is it not working?

Comment: @GertArnold Sorry this query taking considerable time to execute

Comment: @GertArnold Can u please help me to solve this

Comment: What's the database brand and what's the EF version? And what does the generated SQL look like?

Comment: @GertArnold EF 6.2.0, SQL server. how can I see the generating SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm) || m.MemberNumber.Contains(searchTerm)
```

Will require a full scan to find matching rows.

And This:

```
.ToList().Skip(pageIndex).Take(size);
```

Will load all the matching rows before paging, and doesn't have a guaranteed ordering, so you may get duplicates or miss rows across pages.

So at a minimum try (assuming MemberNumber is unique):

```
.OrderBy(m => m.MemberNumber).Skip(pageIndex).Take(size).ToList();
```